# How to programmatically change focus textbox in wpf using MVVM Pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have focused element messagetextbox like this

```
<DockPanel FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=TextBox1}">    
    <TextBox Name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding Message}"/>
    <TextBox Name="TextBox2" Text="{Binding Message}"/>
    <TextBox Name="TextBox3" Text="{Binding Message}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

But later I want to change focus dynamically using elementname to "TextBox2" using code. So how to do this. Suppose I have View Model like this

```
private string elementToFocus;
public string ElementToFocus
{
  set{
    this.elementToFocus=value;
    OnPropertyChanged("ElementToFocus");
  }
  get{
    return this.elementToFocus;
  }
}
```

Anda I want maybe this kind of code but How I can do this?

```
<DockPanel FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName={Binding ElementToFocus}}">
```

Because I have so many control and sometimes move focus programmatically. Thanks

Comment: I think that your requirement is VIEW related, hence you may write the logic in the code behind of the VIEW itself. It might not be needed to touch the ViewModel at all. In other words, you may want to design your view such that it takes care of the focusing on itself

Comment: So it can not be done using `ViewModel` right? I have to use find control by element inside the VIEW am I Right?

Comment: I can not say that, but basically from Design point of view, you must do it in the VIEW part itself of the MVVM

Comment: thanks.. I think someone can suggest best practice using it..

Answer (score 0):

Since setting the Focus is a View related thing, I personally prefer doing it using the Messager Class (Provided by GalaSoft-Mvvmlight), and here how:

1.register you View to receive messages from ViewModels and set the handler for those messages (inside the Constructor of the View):

```
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, (message) =>
        {
            switch (message.Notification)
            {
                case "TextBox1":
                   TextBox1.Focus();
                    break;
               case "TextBox2":
                   TextBox2.Focus();
                    break;
                case "TextBox3":
                   TextBox3.Focus();
                    break;
            }
        });
```

2.When you want to change the focus just send a message from your VM containing the Name of the Control to set the focus to :

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("TextBox1"))
```

Comment: and this won't break the Mvvm principal since the code you are putting in the code behind of the View is related to the view.

Comment: This breaks the MVVM pattern, because views must not publish or subscribe using messengers ! This behavior is only for view models.

Comment: Mvvm is about separation of concerns and reduce coupling between the View and ViewModel (The Logic and the presentation).using the Messenger Class The ViewModel simply broadcasts a Change message to others (View and ViewModel)That Won't introduce any coupling between those two if the View subscribes to that message to do something related to the UI.